How to merge land cover map of raster data using R, terra
I would like to merge land cover maps into one, and I found the code below:
tif_files <- list.files(path = "LandCover",
                          pattern = ".tif$",
                          full.names = TRUE,
                          ignore.case = TRUE
  )
  tif_rasts <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(tif_files)){
    # print(tif_file_name[i])
    tif_rasts <- c(tif_rasts,  rast(tif_files[i]))
  }
  
  
  tif_mosaic <- do.call(mosaic, c(tif_rasts, fun="max"))
  plot(tif_mosaic)
  
  writeRaster(tif_mosaic,
              filename = "land_cover.tif"),
              overwrite = TRUE
  )        

However, I found the final land cover data are into 3 bands (layers), and these layers have the same and different values. I would like to know how to combine them into a single layer in order to identify the land use type represented by each value.
unique(tif_mosaic)
   CHI_1_LULC_1 CHI_1_LULC_2 CHI_1_LULC_3
2             0            0            0
3             0            0          255
4            34          139           34
5           128            0            0
6           128          236          104
7           133          133          133
8           255            0            0
9           255            0          192
10          255          193           37
11          255          255          255


Your question is not very clear. Are you sure your files have different spatial extents? This is important for using mosaic. I also don't think you need a loop.
Without your data, it's hard to help effectively. Here's what I think you want:
library(terra)

tif_files <- list.files(path = "LandCover",
                          pattern = ".tif$",
                          full.names = TRUE)


tif_list <- lapply(tif_files, rast)
final_rast <- do.call(merge, tif_list)


Or something like this:
tif_rasts <- list()
for (i in 1:length(tif_files)){
  tif_list <- rast(tif_files[i]))

tif_rasts = append(tif_rasts, list(tif_list)) #combine the output into a list

}

final_rast = mosaic(rast(tif_rasts))



They are images of land use maps of a city, and divided into many pieces with different spatial extents.

I have updated the answer. But it would be easier to help if you could provide a slice of your data.

Thanks, however, stiil problem. This is the website for data. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ejnBQsaOPiVlwcK75tl6A9TueoM2RjkT

From individual files, it shows that you have multiband (3 bands) files. So, the result you are getting makes sense because the band colours and values mean different things in different bands. I'm not sure what your objectives for the result are. The options are either to use a single band for your work Or to calculate the mean of the final raster (e.g., mean(final_rast)) if you must combine the rasters. Assuming the latter makes sense for your work.

For my object, I need to calculate the landscape matrics for different land cover types, so i need to obtain a map, which has  only one band and unique value for different land cover types.
